# Camunda-Pass parameter between HTTP-CONNECTOR

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to pass output of one REST API to another REST-API in camunda . My first API is returning JSON which has value of email .
I am getting output from first REST-API using HTTP-CONNECTOR script variable

```
<camunda:outputParameter name="email">
              <camunda:script scriptFormat="JavaScript">var value = S(NUMBER, 'application/json');
print("DATA ::: "+ value);
var response = S(connector.getVariable("response"), 'application/json');
print("Response ::: "+ response );
print("Email :::"+ response.prop("email"));
response.prop("email");</camunda:script>
            </camunda:outputParameter>
```

now I want to pass email in payload of another rest-API call for which I am using HTTP-CONNECTOR

```
<camunda:connector>
          <camunda:inputOutput>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="url">http://localhost:8080/step2</camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="method">POST</camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="header">
              <camunda:map>
                <camunda:entry key="accept">application/json</camunda:entry>
                <camunda:entry key="content-type">application/json</camunda:entry>
              </camunda:map>
            </camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="payload">
              <camunda:script scriptFormat="JavaScript">var email=execution.getVariable("email");</camunda:script>
            </camunda:inputParameter>
          </camunda:inputOutput>
          <camunda:connectorId>http-connector</camunda:connectorId>
        </camunda:connector>
```

but it's giving error as

w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported]

How to pass output variable to next REST-API ?

Answer (score 0):

`<camunda:inputParameter name="header">` instead of this `<camunda:inputParameter name="headers">` should be used , more-ever it's not possible to pass script as input to text variable.
so I used

```
<camunda:outputParameter name="email">
             ${response}
</camunda:outputParameter>
```

to pass complete response to next service